# Javascript Take JSON string convert to array

Tags: javascript

*****No JQUERY*****

I have a string passed into my Javascript that looks like below. I want to convert it into an array.

*I have*

```
{"test":"1,180,35"}
```

*I want*

an array where index 0 = 1, index 1 = 180, index 2 = 35.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the string, pull out the property value for property `test`, split it on `,`.

```js
var input = '{"test":"1,180,35"}'
var jsObj = JSON.parse(input);
var arr = jsObj.test.split(",");
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse()` to convert a string into a json object.

But, you are looking to parse a series of numbers into an array, so what you really want is `split(",")`

Comment: "json object" is a misnomer. json is a string format and a javascript object is the result of parsing. So you meant the latter.

Answer (score -1):

Use the JSON object

```
let arr = JSON.parse('{"test":"1,180,35"}').test.split(',');
```

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
var yourData = `{"test":"1,180,35"}`
JSON.parse(yourData).split(',')
```